# Keep window size when resizing font in MacVim

Tags: vim, macvim, zoom

When changing the font size in MacVim on OSX (`Cmd +`,`Cmd -`), the window is resized as well.  Is there a setting that makes MacVim keep its window's size, when the font is resized?

Answer (score 3):

Use `set guioptions+=k`. See https://github.com/macvim-dev/macvim/issues/1006. Probably should be the default but either way the option will work.

Comment: Thank you @ychin!

Answer (score 1):

The window size in MacVim is based on "number of lines and number of columns to be displayed"; if you change the font and font size, those lines and columns need less or more space and the window size is adjusted accordingly.

You can specify the number or lines and columns MacVim will show with `set lines=nn` and `set columns=mm` in `~/.vimrc` to get a starting window size of your liking, but - obviously - when you change the font or font size "on the fly", the window size will also change again.

Comment: Has this been solved with any recent version of MacVim?